# Cannot set vertical position of text in matplotlib table cell

Tags: python, matplotlib, formatting

I want the headers of my table to be rotated and thus have more than one line of height. When I try to bottom align these, however, I cannot get rid of extra space that is padding the bottom of the header text, which increases the larger I set the height of the cell. How can I get the text to be flush with the bottom of the cell?

Manually setting the text position, such as through `cell.get_text().set_y()` does not have any effect as far as I can tell.

```py
data = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
colLabels = ["short", "Long Column Name"]
rowLabels = ["Row A", "Row B"]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, frameon=False, xticks=[], yticks=[])
the_table = ax.table(cellText=data,rowLabels=rowLabels, rowLoc='right', colLabels=colLabels, colLoc='right', loc='center')
for k, cell in the_table._cells.items():
    if k[0] == 0: # header
        cell.get_text().set_rotation(-45)
        cell.get_text().set_verticalalignment('bottom')
        cell.set_height(0.8)
        cell.get_text().set_y(0) # no value seems to do anything
plt.show()
```

[image: Table]

Answer (score 0):

The `Text`'s y position calculated from the `Cell` box is `y0 + height / 2`, and you set the `Text`'s vertical alignment to `"bottom"`, which is the reason for the bottom padding.

All you need to do is set the text rotation, set a proper cell height, and all is done.

```py
for k, cell in the_table._cells.items():
    if k[0] == 0: # header
        cell.get_text().set_rotation(-45)
        cell.set_height(0.4)
```

By the way, calling the private method is not suggested. The following is an alternative:

```py
for (row, col), cell in the_table.get_celld().items():
    if row == 0:
        cell.get_text().set_rotation(-45)
        cell.set_height(0.4)
```

Comment: Is there any way to then get the text to align at the bottom, such that the t in "short" and e in "Name" are aligned, without the excessive padding?

Comment: Sorry, I don't find any way either.